# Partial support in VS 2013 for certificates and symmetric keys in azure v12

Tags: azure, encryption, visual-studio-2013, azure-sql-database

In a Visual Studio 2013 project targeting azure v12, I get SQL70015 errors (Statement x is not supported in the targeted platform) when creating key and certificate artifacts.

However, before creating independent key and certificate objects in the project, I'd had a postdeploy script add them if they didn't exist.  That postdeploy script worked flawlessly...but of course, I'd get SQL71502 warnings (unresolved objects) when I refer to the key in other artifacts such as triggers and procedures...hence the desire to move to plain ol' VS key and certificate objects.

I wonder if I'm doing something wrong or if I have misconfigured my development environment.  I have Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1, Azure SDK v 2.6, SQL 2012 and SQL 2014 installed locally and am successfully deploying to azure.  I would sure like to normalize the project, but I'm stuck using the postdeploy and living with the warnings.

To be clear, my postdeploy has:

```
if not exists ( select * from sys.symmetric_keys where symmetric_key_id = 101 )
create master key encryption by password = '$(MasterKeyEncryption)'

go
if not exists ( select * from sys.certificates where subject = 'User Account Certificate' )
create certificate UserAccountCertificate with subject = 'User Account Certificate'

go
if not exists ( select * from sys.symmetric_keys where name='UserAccountKey' )
create symmetric key UserAccountKey with algorithm = aes_256 encryption by certificate UserAccountCertificate
```

...which worked fine.  However, stand-alone artifacts, such as:

```
create certificate UserAccountCertificate with subject = 'User Account Certificate'
```

...produce the SQL70015 errors.  And, here is a successful test of the key as run in azure:

```
declare 
   @plaintext nvarchar(max), 
   @ciphertext nvarchar(max);
open symmetric key UserAccountKey decryption by certificate UserAccountCertificate;

select @plaintext = 'here lies the original message';
select @ciphertext = encryptbykey( key_guid( 'UserAccountKey' ), @plaintext );
select convert(nvarchar( max ),decryptbykey( @ciphertext ) ), @ciphertext;
close symmetric key UserAccountKey;
```

Has anybody else encountered this problem?  Is it just a transient error in VS support for azure v12?  Should I reinstall a bunch of stuff?  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for Cell-Level Encryption in Azure SQL Database was recently introduced as a preview feature in SQL Database V12. The main reason this feature is still in preview is that unfortunately we are still working on proper tooling support to handle these objects properly.

One thing you need to consider when using this feature in Azure SQL Database is that while certificates can easily be extracted and recreated on a different database, the same is not necessarily true for all key objects, such as symmetric keys. If you are careful to create symmetric keys using the KEY_SOURCE & IDENTITY_VALUE fields in the DDL, then they can be recreated in another database.

However, many scripts (such as those used by the tools) create keys using syntax like:

```
create symmetric key UserAccountKey 
  with algorithm = aes_256 
  encryption by certificate UserAccountCertificate
```

This will create a symmetric key with different (random) key material on every instantiation; in other words, every time you run this DDL statement, the generated key will be different. Any data encrypted by a symmetric key created this way cannot be copied to another database as there is no way to move the symmetric key to the new database.

This means that any data encrypted by a randomly generated symmetric key in one database cannot be copied to another database. While in many cases this may be acceptable for a particular application (i.e. each database is a stand-alone entity, data does not move between them), it is not true for all applications. If an application expects to move the data from one database to another (for example, when creating or merging shards), accidental misuse could lead to data loss.

I'd encourage you to check out this article for more detailed information on using Cell-Level Encryption features in Azure SQL Database: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlsecurity/archive/2015/05/12/recommendations-for-using-cell-level-encryption-in-azure-sql-database.aspx

Comment: Excellent post - I appreciate the advice on making the keys portable.  It's something I hadn't considered.  Will it always be true that when using a key_source, triple_des will be the key encrypting algorithm, or will this ultimately be configurable?  I'm not super excited about having triple_des as my only option - but it will cover the bases for now.

Comment: Almost 18 months later and I'm getting the same issue that @Clay reported (SQL70015), due to the existence of certificates or keys in the Azure SQL Database.  

This is in VS 2015 and VS 2017 RC, and breaks the SQL Server Object Explorer and Database Project (build as well as compare), making CLE useless to us.  

I can't see anything still saying the Cell-Level Encryption is in Preview for Azure: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms179331.aspx